# Python os.rename() multiple files caused all but last file to go missing

Tags: python

The code below runs without any errors or warnings.  It takes a list of old to new file names and places it into a dictionary keyed on old file name.  It then reads all file names for a given path into a list.  It then traverses the list for each file name and looks for a hit in the dictionary.  If a hit is found, the file name (path+name) will be renamed to (path+val).

The path contains 361 files which includes the hidden .DS_Store file. The code filters out the hidden file leaving the 360 file names I wish to rename.  All of the files of interest begin with '0' thru '9'.  All 360 file names are found in the dictionary.

After execution, there is only one file remaining in the path.  Its the last of 360 files and it is renamed.  The other 359 files are gone.  Why? Where did they go?  What am I missing?

I saw several posts related to os.rename but none that answered this question.

Thank you
Dan

```
import os

# File name positions: OLD 0 to 113  NEW 115 to end of line
new_list = open("/Users/testfolder/new_list.txt", "r")

# Define a file dictionary
file_dict = {}

# Load contents of new_list into the file dictionary.
# KEY=old file name, VAL=New file name
for line in new_list:
    (key, val) = line[0:114].strip(), line[115:].strip()
    file_dict[key] = val

#print(file_dict)

# Path where files reside
path='/Users/testfolder/files/'

# Define a list of files in the path
files = []
file_path_count=0
file_to_rename_count=0
files_renamed=0
for name in os.listdir(path):
    file_path_count +=1
    print('name: ',name)
    # If valid path/file that begins with number 0 thru 9
    # .DS_Store file will be omitted from rename logic
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name)) and name[0] in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'):
        files.append(name.strip())
        file_to_rename_count +=1
        #print('file to rename: ', name)
        # If the file name in path is found in the file_dict, key=name
        if file_dict.get(name.strip(),'Not Found') == 'Not Found':
            print('not found in file_dict')
        else:
            # File found in file_dict. Rename old file name to new file name
            print('***** renaming: ', path+name, ' to: ', path+file_dict.get(name))
            os.rename(path+name, path+val)
            files_renamed +=1

files.sort()
print('files in the path to rename: ',files)  
print('Number of files found in path: ',file_path_count)  # Count includes .DS_Store file

# The following two counts match and are one less than file_path_count as expected
print('Number of files to rename: ',file_to_rename_count) # Count excluding .DS_Store
print('Number of files renamed: ',files_renamed) # Count Excluding .DS_Store

# After running this program, all but the last file in "path" are missing.  Why, and where did they go?
```

Comment: `val` is never reassigned, it will retain whatever value it had at the end of the loop where it was first used.

Comment: Ok but how does this cause the results I outlined and where did the files go?

Comment: If you are running this on Unix, then you have overwritten the files with the rename operation. From the documentation about [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename), "On Unix ... If both are files, dst it will be replaced silently if the user has permission."

Comment: @Craig that's just evil.  Any sensible OS would simply fail the request.

Comment: Huh. I never realized it raises a `FileExistsError` on Windows. That's definitely worth noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `val` is never reassigned, it will retain whatever value it had at the end of the loop where it was first used.
> – [vanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224508/vanza)

To expand on vanza's comment, here is a simplified example of what's going on.

```py
old_names = ['murder', 'arson', 'jaywalking']
new_names = ['spam', 'eggs', 'baked beans']

# This is analagous to your first for loop...
for new_name in new_names:
    val = new_name

# We're now done assigning to val, so for the rest of the program,
# val == 'baked beans'

# This is analagous to your second for loop...
for index in range(len(old_names)):
    # Every single time we replace an item in the list, val is still the
    # same.
    old_names[index] = val

print(old_names)
# Output: ['baked beans', 'baked beans', 'baked beans']
```

So what you've done is that you've gone through all your your files, and renamed each of them to the same name. That means the second one will overwrite the first one, the third will overwrite the second, and so on, until all you're left with is the final file that you rename.

---

On another note, a lot of file/folder operations one can do with `os` are often a lot more cleanly and conveniently done with [pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/). I recommend checking it out, it's pretty great.

Comment: Ok, I see what I did now.  Junior error :)
'''
   print('***** renaming: ', path+name, ' to: ', path+file_dict.get(name))
   os.rename(path+name, path+val)
'''
I think back to my early days of programming (i am now retired).  A picture of a guy shaking a pc saying "Listen to me when I am programming you!"
What I did was print exactly what I expected to happen but the os operation overwrote the files as you have pointed out.
Changing the os.rename as follows produces the desired outcome.
'''
 os.rename(path+name, path+file_dict.get(name))
''' 
Thank you all for opening my eyes.
Dan